# Image in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the image of the curve z=|z| under the mapping defined by w=1/z.

So |z|=$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$  so w=1/$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$= u+iv. So u=1/$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, v=0.

Is this the right direction, and what do I do from here?

Answer (score 0):

Am I supposed to read is as $f(z)=|z|$ ? Then the absolute value of complex number z is a REAL number. And so this curve consists off all real numbers. And so when you reciprocate a real number, it is again a real number. So in the complex plane, where do we find all the real numbers? That is the result of this mapping. (with the exception of the origin, but you know why...)

Or are we looking at the solutions of the equation $z=|z|$? Then we have $a+bi=\sqrt(a^2+b^2)$ which reduces to $ab=0$ meaning $a=0$ or $b=0$ This means the positive real axis.

Comment: It happens that $z=|z|$ is the positive real line, whereas $f(z)=|z|$ might be any curve in the plane, depending on $f$.

Comment: @Jonathan  So I guess it is my second approach? (I edited)

Comment: It doesn't reduce to $ab=0$, but rather to $b=0\wedge a\geq 0$, which indeed is the positive real line.

Comment: @JonathanY. Yes, with respect to the problem, it has to be the positive real line